# Maximum number of lines for generated CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have problem with function that generate CSV in my site. It give me Error 500. When I check in apache error log, there is no record for this problem. After i dig the code, i find out that this error will come out if the data for CSV file is more than 1550 lines.

I was thought that setting for `max_execution_time` in php.ini is too low but after I increased it to 600sec, it still cannot generate CSV file more than 1550 lines of data.

Any idea how to solve this problem? Anyone know what happen actually?

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? What's your max memory limit?

Comment: error reporting is enabled. My memory limit is 128M

Comment: There must be something wrong with your configuration then. You should get a PHP error instead of a generic 500 error ...

Answer (score 1):

Also, look into [set_time_limit](http://php.net/set_time_limit).

One thing to consider, is that some cloud side host providers (e.g. RackSpace) implement timeouts in their load balancers, which will terminate connections if there is no traffic (see [Rackspace Connection Timed Out Error](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/content/connection-timed-out-error)).

One possible workaround for that, is to echo and flush data back to the client to keep the connection open. This can be a simple HTML comment of whatever you want.

The more recommended solution is to offload lengthy processes to a script executed via a CRON job.  There are plenty of PHP job daemon examples out there.  A job daemon isn't necessary, a simple PHP script that processes a database table is sufficient enough for smaller solutions.

Answer (score 0):

try adding 
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);

Also test the csv file, try opening it and resaving it.